# Bootstrap 3: changing column orders in 2 different lines using push and pull

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following layout of page (desktop) view:

```
+-------------+
| A(6) | B(6) |
+-------------+
|    C(12)    |
+-------------+
|    D(12)    |
+-------------+
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">A</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">B</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">C</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">D</div>
```

For the mobile I want the markup to look like this:

```
+-------------+
|    A(12)    |
+-------------+
|    C(12)    |
+-------------+
|    B(12)    |
+-------------+
|    D(12)    |
+-------------+
```

I've tried to use mobile-first approach with pull/push and came up with such HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-lg-push-6">C</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-12">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">D</div>
```

But in desktop it does not look like I expect:

```
                             +-------------+
                             |    A(6)     |
                             +-------------+---------------------------+
                                           |           C(12)           |
+-------------+                            +---------------------------+
|   B(12)     |            
+-------------+              +---------------------------+
                             |           D(12)           |
                             +---------------------------+
```

UPDATE: 
looks like the question is misunderstood: the main issue is to change order of B and C for mobile view.

Comment: If you want to change the order you should probably look into using flexbox, browser support is in decent shape these days, and the worst thing that would happen on browsers lacking support (IE9) is the order stays as it is now. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Looks interesting. I haven't heard about flexbox yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">C</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">D</div>
```

No need for the pull and push , all you have to do is

```
text-align:center;
```

if you need to center the div content.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10594/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the solution does not really work.
I don't care about text alignment inside the blocks. What I need is to make proper layout.

Comment: What's not woking exactly please specify

Comment: btw lg is large ,  desktop starts at md (medium) if you have a medium screen try it with col-md-* instead col-lg-*

Comment: What I need to do is to change order of B and C for mobile view. Anyway thanks! Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Okay now I got you I guess I have a work around but I will test it first , sorry for missunderstanding